Adding Icon to MenuFlyoutItem in XAML
I'm trying to add an icon to MenuFlyoutItem. I have the following project structure:
Project
-Resources
--Images
---image.png
-Views
--View.xaml
The XAML is as follows:
<MenuFlyoutItem
    Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SomeCommand}"
    Style="{StaticResource SomeStyle}"
    Width="Auto">
    <MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
        <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Resources/Images/image.png"/>
    </MenuFlyoutItem.Icon>
</MenuFlyoutItem>

but I don't see the icon in the menu item.
I'm expecting to have something like this:

I tried to add an Image control to the view and to specify "/Resources/Images/image.png" as a source of the image, just to check if I can reach that image.png file, and in this case my image is displayed no problem.
Please help me, what am I doing wrong with MenuFlyoutItem?
Thanks.

1.Please check if image.png is in the folder /Resources/Images/ 
2.Please right-click image.png in Solution Explorer, select Properties.
In the Properties window, check if the Build Action is Content.


Hi, as I wrote I tried to insert this image in Image control and it is displayed, so yes, the image is in the folder. Build Action is set to Content.

According to the BitmapIcon , the file that you use should be a solid image on a transparent background. The bitmap image as retrieved from the UriSource location is expected to be a true bitmap that has transparent pixels and non-transparent pixels. The recommended format is PNG.

It is recommended that you check whether your image meets the requirements, or use the default image Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png in Assets for testing.

@P32017Step Is my comment helpful to you?

I have a .png file in my Images folder and it is written in my question post, the size is 18x18.

This is my project directory and my test result.

@P32017Step, has your problem been solved?
